# How do I start in doing unit testing my web component with mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, web-component

I am currently tasked in creating a unit test for a web-component using mocha. My first Idea is to do something like `document.createElement('custom-component')` and then check the `innerHTML` or the attribute if I want to check for correctness, but I know that I cannot do that since the document is not yet defined. Is there a way to approach this problem?

Comment: Take a look at [`jsdom`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#--------jsdom)

Comment: You could use Mocha together with a headless or complete browser, for example with chaijs

Comment: I use Karma to test mine. https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Doing web component testing in mocha alone is probably pretty tough. You will need some combination of mocha, chai, karma, some helpers, probably webpack (for legacy browsers), ...

There is this setup at https://open-wc.org/testing/ - I think it should give you all you need.